# Trying to convert SQL query to use joins instead of nested queries. I need to do using oracle joins only

Tags: sql, oracle

Convert below query to use Oracle joins instead of nested queries/ subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM EXPORT_TABLE doe
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND doe.last_update_date < SYSDATE - 1
   AND ID NOT IN (
                   SELECT ID
                     FROM EXPORT_TABLE
                    WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE IN (
                                                SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
                                                  FROM EXPORT_TABLE
                                                 GROUP BY DI_EXTRACT_ID
                                              )
                 )
```

I have tried below query but not getting same result like subquery

```sql
SELECT distinct doe.*
  FROM EXPORT_TABLE doe,
       (SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
              ,max(ID) id
          FROM EXPORT_TABLE
         GROUP BY DI_EXTRACT_ID) sort_table
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND doe.id <> sort_table.id
   AND doe.last_update_date < SYSDATE - 1
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve and what is wrong with the current query with `in`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it querying the table only once (without any joins) using only analytic functions (however, without sample data to test against it is difficult to confirm the behaviours are identical):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         MIN(rnk) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS min_rnk
  FROM   (
    SELECT d.*,
           RANK() OVER (
             PARTITION BY DI_EXTRACT_ID
             ORDER     BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC
           ) AS rnk
    FROM   EXPORT_TABLE d
  ) d
)
WHERE  last_update_date < SYSDATE - 1
AND    min_rnk > 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AlDDRU6N)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a left anti-join to get rows from EXPORT_TABLE having no match in the original subquery.

```
 SELECT distinct doe.*  
 FROM EXPORT_TABLE doe
 left join(SELECT ID 
           FROM EXPORT_TABLE 
           WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE IN (
              SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE) 
              FROM EXPORT_TABLE 
              GROUP BY DI_EXTRACT_ID)) sort_table
 on AND doe.id=sort_table.id
 where doe.last_update_date < SYSDATE - 1
    and sort_table.id is null
```

Also note replacing original subquery

```
           SELECT ID 
           FROM EXPORT_TABLE 
           WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE IN (
              SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE) 
              FROM EXPORT_TABLE 
              GROUP BY DI_EXTRACT_ID)
```

with

```
       SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE),max(ID)  id
       FROM EXPORT_TABLE 
       GROUP BY DI_EXTRACT_ID
```

may be wrong. Generally those are two quit different queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `LEFT JOIN` with a where condition to match only records not in `MAX(last_update_date)`

```
SELECT doe.*
FROM EXPORT_TABLE doe
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(last_update_date) as MAX_last_update_date
  FROM EXPORT_TABLE
  GROUP BY DI_EXTRACT_ID
) t ON t.MAX_last_update_date = doe.last_update_date
WHERE t.MAX_last_update_date is null
ORDER BY doe.id
```

An other way to do it using `INNER JOIN` with a list of IDs that are not matching `MAX(last_update_date)` :

```
SELECT doe.*
FROM EXPORT_TABLE doe
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM EXPORT_TABLE
  WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
    FROM EXPORT_TABLE
    GROUP BY DI_EXTRACT_ID
  )
) t ON t.ID = doe.ID
ORDER BY doe.ID
```